# Being dependant on a preferGlobal package

Tags: node.js, configuration, npm

If I am trying to use a package that has the `preferGlobal` option.

How do I add `jshint` as a dependency to the `package.json` so I don't get the following message

```
npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add `jshint` to your `devDependencies`, simply run

```
npm install --save-dev jshint
```

and `npm` will add it to your `package.json` for you. You really don't have to fret about the warning if you know what you're doing (i.e. you are going to use `jshint` in one of your [`npm` scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)). If it bothers you a lot, you can configure your [`loglevel`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel) to reduce the noise:

```
npm config set loglevel error
```

but note that by doing this you will miss out on other, potentially important warnings.

Comment: so there is no `checkGlobalDependencies` that will complain and crash saying to install global first?

Comment: Correct, this should not cause anything to "crash".